# PHP setcookie() issue

Tags: php, cookies

I've not done cookies in like 10 years.  I have a simple php login script, which is checking a username and password against values in a MySQL database.  If it succeeds, I create I set a cookie... try to , anyway.

I can get setcookie() to return true, but the cookie isn't set.  I realize most of the time this is b/c headers have been sent.  EDIT: headers_sent() is returning false, so that's not the issue.

The session code (not to be confused with a PHP session()):

```
function create_session( &$user_id, &$ip, &$proxy_ip )
{
     global $mysqli_auc;

    $hash   = md5( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
    $query  = "INSERT INTO user_sessions(user_id,ip,proxy_ip,session_hash)
           VALUES('$user_id','$ip','$proxy_ip','$hash')";
    $result = $mysqli_auc->query( $query );

    $already_sent = "false";
    if ( headers_sent() ) {
        $already_sent = "true";
    }

    // print "This definitely sends headers";
    if ( !setcookie( "my_hash",$hash,time()+2000 ) ) {
        print "Unable to set cookie.<br>";
    } else {
        print "Set cookie. " . $_COOKIE['my_hash'] . "<br>"; // blank
        print "Should be " . $hash . "<br>"; // this holds an md5 hash string
        print "Headers sent " . $already_sent "<br>"; // false
    }
}
```

Comment: Cookies do not immediately appear in the current invocations `$_COOKIE`, but after the next HTTP roundtrip.

Comment: Thanks.  However, worth mentioning, I was checking my browser and they weren't there.  Must have been a bug as it's there now.  Thanks.  Not sure if it qualifies as an answer but I will accept it if you offer it as one!

Answer (score 0):

`$_COOKIE` superglobal only holds cookies sent by the client in the request's `Cookie:` header.
`setcookie()` doesn't change it, it only sets what will be sent in the response's `Set-Cookie:` header.

BTW, what you seem to use as session identifier is extremely insecure. Not only it's not guaranteed to be unique, but also very easy to predict / spoof.

Comment: I'm just doing some testing now.  I'll use something more secure once I get closer to release.